# Phantomjs - set border (and color) of created image

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, phantomjs, rasterizing

I use [this](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Screen-Capture) to generate html page as image. So, my command looks something like this:

```
$ phantomjs rasterize.js 'http://example.com' image.png
```

Is it possible to set border and color for generating image via phantomjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, well, it looks like it's impossible to do that via phantomjs. I choose another solution, via [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). I installed it and now i use something like this:

```
$ convert input_img.png -bordercolor "LimeGreen" -compose Copy -border 4 output_img.png
```